# transforming XML into text using xsl with Java

Tags: transformation

I use Java to convert XML files into text with statements like:

transformer.transform(source, result)

When I run the java program this statement displays information about compiling the style sheet, e.g.

"XL TXE-J compiling stylesheet: file:///C:/myDir/myFile.xsl"

how do I suppress this display? I know it must be simple but I'm not a developer, just scratching the surface...

Answer (score 0):

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/realtime/v2r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rt.doc.20%2Fuser%2Fxml%2Fxslt_migrate.html

maybe this page will help, I suggest you try disabling debug or change back to xslt4j instead of the xl txe-j.

also you could try adding a messagehandler to "process" the messages.

Comment: Hello, i found this in the link "To continue using the XSLT4J interpreter as your XSLT processor, set the javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory service provider to org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl" how do you do that? I have import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory; in the java code. Thanks

Comment: I prefer to use xltxe-j but just don't want those compiling messages to disply, they disturb the system out messages that are in the code. If there is a way to wrap the transformer.transform(source, result) commands to suppress the display??

Comment: I think they are printed to stderr or out by some default errorhandler. I would at first ask IBM since it is their product,secondly i would experiment with setting all errorhandlers to dummy implementations to block the default implementations from sending stuff to stderr.

Comment: third, if you dont need compiling , try disabling compiling to see if the messages disappear..

Comment: but how do i do this? send err handling to dummy or disable compiling?

Comment: there are some output to console (using System.out.println ) that i would still want to display

Comment: umm.set an errorlistener to the transformerfactory or to the transformer.